# Help replacing link in text form field with hyperlink

Tags: javascript, regex, coldfusion

I don't have much experience with regex, but I assume that is what I need to use. I have a page in coldfusion that I am submitting info using several functions with ajax. One of the form fields is "comment". I would like to be able to find any links in the comment field, ie: http://www.yahoo.com and replace it with a working link. Thanks for any help you can offer. Function is below:

```
<code>
function AddComment(reqid)
{
    var Comment = '';

    if(document.getElementById('Comment').value != "")
    {
        Comment = document.getElementById('Comment').value;     

        request = getRequest();
        if (!request)
         alert("Error initializing XMLHttpRequest!");

        var url = "#webroot#view-requests-action.cfm?id=" + escape(reqid) + '&Comment=' + escape(Comment) + '&section=' + 'addcomm';
    //alert(url) 
    //return;
        request.open("GET", url, false);
        request.send(null);
        window.location="view-requests.cfm?id=#url.id#&panel=0";
    }
    else
    {
    window.location="view-requests.cfm?id=#url.id#&panel=0";
    }
}   
</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it via JavaScript.

```
sampleText = "Hello World! http://www.google.com";
function InsertLinks(message)
{
    var words = message.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        if (words[i].indexOf("http:") >= 0)
        {
            words[i] = '<a href="' + words[i] + '">' + words[i] + "</a>";
        }
    }
    return words.join(" ");
}       

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = InsertLinks(sampleText);
```

The code above will return the following as a string:

```
Hello World! <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com<a>
```

-edit
This is how to implement it via your function:

```
Comment = InsertLinks(document.getElementById('Comment').value);
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense, but am having trouble getting it to work with my current code.

Comment: The code sample above requires the url be in "http: then url" format.  To use this code just paste in the function in your library or page, and wherever you "output" this string to the page you replace it with InsertLinks(yourVariableHere).